# Apply Function Handle to Multiple Input Arguments

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function, cell-array, function-handle

I have a matrix and a vector in MATLAB defined:

```
A=rand(3);
x=rand(3,1);
```

And a function that takes these types of input arguments:

```
b = MacVecProd(A,x);
```

However, I'd like to use this function's function handle in order to apply it to my values.  I thought that I could use `cellfun` for this, but:

```
v = {A,x};
cellfun(@MatVecProd_a, v{:})
```

Gives the error:

```
Error using cellfun
Input #2 expected to be a cell array, was double instead.
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Why are you making a cell at all? Just call the function directly with the double array arguments.

Comment: why don't you just do A * [x1, x2, ... , xn], where the x's are column vectors..? it would give what you want: [b1, b2, ..., bn]...

Comment: In reality, my problem is not as simple as the one I posed.  I have a large array of functions, each of which takes a matrix and a column vector as inputs.  I'd like to apply each function on my matrix and vector and accumulate the results into a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define your own, special function to call anonymous functions with given parameters, e.g.:

```
% define special function to call function handles
myfuncall = @(fh, v) fh(v{:});

% execute MacVecProd using myfuncall
b = myfuncall(@MacVecProd, v)
```

Based on your comment that you have array of functions and you want to execute them for your input arguments, you could do as follows:

```
  % cell array of function handles
  myFunctioins = {@MacVecProd, @MacVecProd2, @MacVecProd3};

  % execute each function with v parameters
  % I assume you want to execute them for the same input v
  resultCell = cellfun(@(fh) fh(v{:}), myFunctioins, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```